# How to create temporary tables in a RDS replica instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication

My developers are asking me to be able to create [Temporary Tables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm).

But the connection they have configured is connected to a [RDS Read Replica Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/read-replicas/).

How can I set up privileges so their connection can create Temporary Tables in that instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a connection with an User with **'ALL' privileges** to your **master RDS** instance and create a `tmp` database as a store point for the Temporary Tables:

```
create database if not exists tmp;
```

Assign `SELECT` and `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES` to your replica user's connection:

```
grant SELECT, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON tmp.* TO youruser@'%';
```

Now though your replica connection you can manipulate Temporary Tables:

```
create temporary table tmp.my_temporary_table
  select 
    mt.id
  from my_databaes.my_table as mt
  limit 10;

select * from tmp.my_temporary_table;

drop temporary table tmp.my_temporary_table;
```

Comment: What does it mean "writing privileges connection"? How to open it?

Comment: @Andremoniy Open a connection with an User with **'ALL' privileges** .. or at least enough privileges to create DBs and modifying privileges on DBs. Which is normally your `root` User. _(wording changed in the answer to avoid ambiguity)_

Comment: Ah, ok, it is `mysql`... not suitable for postgres

Comment: Seem to be able to create temporary tables but not update them. So, only of limited use.